# Query is running slow with equal operator

Tags: sql, oracle

The following query is working fine (fast) when I use `emp.status >= 412` or `emp.status <= 412` or without `emp.status` filter, but when I use only equal operator, i.e. `emp.status = 412`, my query is running too slow.

What's the problem? Could it be some indexing issue? I have created an index on status field.

```
SELECT emp.empno FROM EMP_STATUS emp WHERE
     emp.empno in 
     (
      SELECT schemp.empno FROM  sched_emp schemp,sections scts 
      WHERE    schemp.SECTSCODE = scts.SECTSCODE   AND schemp.dep_code = scts.dep_code    AND scts.years=2014    
      AND schemp.dep_code = 2 
     )
     and emp.dep_code = 2
      and  emp.status  = 412
```

Comment: Have you ran and compared the EXPLAIN statements for both queries? They might provide valuable hints.

Comment: yes both are approximate same.

Comment: Sounds like your table's statistics are not available or broken. The dbms thinks to look for >= 412 or <= 412 is not worth using an index, but = 412 is. But what if 412 makes for 90% of the table? Then an index is not appropriate and the statistics would tell the dbms so.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the execution plan of each query and compare them to know in details what the engine is doing to execute each of them

If there is a long path in the equal case, which is supposed to be as long as you say it take so long

Then try to run `Update Statistics` on your table or on your entire database

This should optimize the execution plan based on the nature of data on your table

For more details about Execution Plans, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan)

For more details about `Update Statistics`, [check this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510198.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks like indexing problem. Try to drop index on status field, 80% it will help. Alternatively, you should gather statistics with histograms.

Anyway, first you should do in such case - look at execution plan (EXPLAIN PLAN mentioned above). It sounds like your query is fast when using FULL TABLE SCAN, but slow if using INDEX access.